# How do i implement DynaJIT library alongside a cache interpreter in a Chip-8 emulator

Tags: c, assembly, emulation

I am working on optimizing my existing Chip-8 emulator by adding just-in-time (JIT) compilation to speed up opcode execution using the DynaJIT dynamic code generation library. I would like to also add an instruction cache for frequently executed instructions to run much more faster

My primary concern is ensuring that both JIT and caching mechanisms work together without causing issues or bugs during runtime. i am particularly lost;

What design patterns should be employed when integrating DynaJIT into a Chip-8 emulator?

My Chip-8 has only 35 distinct opcodes, would creating static lookup tables provide better performance than dynamically generating code through the DynaJIT library?

I attempted to integrate the DynaJIT library into my Chip-8 emulator and add an instruction cache for frequently executed opcodes. My expectations were:

Faster emulation speed
Reduced latency in executing common opcodes thanks to the LRU-based instruction cache.

After testing, I noticed several issues:

Merging DynaJIT into the Chip-8 emulator required significant modifications to accommodate its unique architecture and API which led to complexity and maintenance difficulties.

Ensuring consistent behavior between the JIT-generated code and the instruction cache proved difficult since updating one component often necessitated modifying the other. Maintaining data integrity became increasingly complex over time.

Comment: An old aphorism is "There are two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation and naming things."  But what are you caching?  Your emulator will run on a CPU with hardware caches.  Are you caching JIT results for basic blocks or loops or something, and invalidating them if the guest code stores near some instructions you're caching?  Also, lookup tables of what?  Of native code sequences to copy into a buffer for each guest instruction?

Comment: You keep mentioning some "DynaJIT library", but if such a library exists it appears to be completely unknown by google, because the only software-related search result I get is your stackoverflow post.